# how get List<myClass> from element another List, i get CastList

Tags: flutter, dart

My error:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Food' in type cast
```

I get the list from the server, using fromJson I get it in the format I need

this class contains another list of another class and I can't interact with it. when I try to pull something from the built-in list, I get an error, and the list is displayed as CastList

my class:

```
class FoodGroup{
  @PrimaryKey()
  int id;

  String name;

  List<Food> foods;

  FoodGroup({this.name,
    this.id,
    this.foods});

  FoodGroup.map(dynamic obj) {
    this.id = obj["id"];
    this.foods = obj["foods"].cast<Food>();
    this.name = obj["name"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["id"] = id;
    map["foods"] = foods;
    map["name"] = name;
    return map;
  }

  FoodGroup.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        foods = json['foods'].cast<Food>(),
        name = json['name'];
}
```

. cast() I need to decode from json:

```
var l = jsonDecode(r.body) as List;
foodTable = l.map((i) => FoodGroup.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

with FoodGroup everything is ok, the problem is in List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used json annotation and autogeneration code, this solved the problems with deserializing the nested list, but the number of files in the project has increased significantly, not very nice